# intentar obtener un valor determinado en una respuesta de una api

Tags: json, api, php5

Sigo sin poder obtener un dato determinado incluido en la respuesta de una api.
Esta es la respuesta de la api al realizar la tarea de agregar un registro, lo cual lo hace correctamente y me da como resultado esto:

```
{ "data": { "type": "Opportunity", "id": "32d47f3e-637f-bb51-51c0-627058819b82", "attributes": { "name": "50176 - RODRIGUEZ CARMEN E. - ARLA ALEJANDRO - Ambiente", "date_entered": "2022-05-02T08:00:00+00:00", "date_modified": "2022-05-02T22:15:00+00:00", "modified_user_id": "1306c841-a240-211e-1c81-625053efb533", "modified_by_name": "Integracion WEB", "created_by": "1306c841-a240-211e-1c81-625053efb533", "created_by_name": "Integracion WEB", "description": "llega", "deleted": "0", "created_by_link": "", "modified_user_link": "", "assigned_user_id": "", "assigned_user_name": "", "assigned_user_link": "", "SecurityGroups": "", "opportunity_type": "Ambiente", "account_name": "RODRIGUEZ CARMEN E.", "account_id": "557", "campaign_id": "", "campaign_name": "", "campaign_opportunities": {}, "lead_source": "", "amount": "", "amount_usdollar": "", "currency_id": "-99", "currency_name": "US Dollars", "currency_symbol": "$", "date_closed": "", "next_step": "", "sales_stage": "", "probability": "", "accounts": "", "contacts": "", "tasks": "", "notes": "", "meetings": "", "calls": "", "emails": "", "documents": "", "project": "", "leads": "", "campaigns": "", "campaign_link": "", "currencies": "", "aos_quotes": "", "aos_contracts": "", "fi_baja_c": "", "fi_inspeccion_c": "", "fi_obradireccion_c": "", "regional_ingreso_c": "", "fi_fechaaviso_c": "", "fi_porc_c": "", "fi_epec_c": "", "fi_fecha_c": "", "fi_estaen_c": "", "fi_codobra_c": "", "opportunities_aos_pdf_templates_1": "", "fi_nume_c": "", "ascensores_c": "0", "opportunities_knn_tareasexpediente_1": "", "fi_es_ersep_c": "0", "knn_comitente_id_c": "", "fi_corre_c": "", "jjwg_maps_lng_c": "0.00000000", "fi_desde_c": "", "fi_comi_c": "", "fi_recibido_c": "", "fi_obra_cp_c": "", "es_epec_c": "0", "fi_obs_c": "", "aviso_obra_c": "", "fi_expe_c": "50176", "jjwg_maps_lat_c": "0.00000000", "fi_obra_localidad_c": "", "fi_obra_c": "", "fi_vari_c": "", "fi_montohono_c": "", "retirado_por_c": "", "fi_prof_c": "", "fi_tarea_c": "", "fi_carpetas_c": "", "fecha_salida_c": "", "fi_montoobra_c": "", "comitente_c": "", "es_particular_c": "0", "jjwg_maps_geocode_status_c": "", "detalle_motivo_c": "", "fi_reg_c": "", "fi_ersep_c": "", "fi_id_c": "", "fi_alta_c": "", "fi_cert_c": "", "nroexpediente_c": "", "fi_distribuidor_c": "", "jjwg_maps_address_c": "", "motivo_cierre_c": "", "estado_c": "Activo", "fi_fecha_c_formato_aux_c": "", "quienretirafo_c": "", "fechasalidadefo_c": "" }, "relationships": { "AOS_Contracts": { "links": { "related": "V8/module/32d47f3e-637f-bb51-51c0-627058819b82/relationships/aos_contracts" } }, "AOS_PDF_Templates": { "links": { "related": "V8/module/32d47f3e-637f-bb51-51c0-627058819b82/relationships/opportunities_aos_pdf_templates_1" } }, "AOS_Quotes": { "links": { "related": "V8/module/32d47f3e-637f-bb51-51c0-627058819b82/relationships/aos_quotes" } }, "Accounts": { "links": { "related": "V8/module/32d47f3e-637f-bb51-51c0-627058819b82/relationships/accounts" } }, "CampaignLog": { "links": { "related": "V8/module/32d47f3e-637f-bb51-51c0-627058819b82/relationships/campaigns" } }, "Campaigns": { "links": { "related": "V8/module/32d47f3e-637f-bb51-51c0-627058819b82/relationships/campaign_link" } }, "Contacts": { "links": { "related": "V8/module/32d47f3e-637f-bb51-51c0-627058819b82/relationships/contacts" } }, "KNN_TareasExpediente": { "links": { "related": "V8/module/32d47f3e-637f-bb51-51c0-627058819b82/relationships/opportunities_knn_tareasexpediente_1" } }, "SecurityGroups": { "links": { "related": "V8/module/32d47f3e-637f-bb51-51c0-627058819b82/relationships/SecurityGroups" } }, "Users": { "links": { "related": "V8/module/32d47f3e-637f-bb51-51c0-627058819b82/relationships/created_by_link" } } } } }
```

el dato a obtener es fi_expe_c que en este caso sería 50176 pero no logro entender como resolverlo.

Adjunto código a ver si me pueden dar una mano.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => 'http://url',
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
"data": {
    "type": "Opportunities",
    "attributes": {
        "account_name": "'.$name.'",
        "opportunity_type": "'.$tipoexp.'",
        "description": "'.$descripcion.'",
        "comitente_c": "'.$comitente.'",
        "account_id": "'.$id_ciec_c.'"
    }
}
}',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Authorization: Bearer '.$permiso,
),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print_r($response);
$datos = json_decode($response, true);
$name = $datos['data'][0]['attributes']['fi_expe_c'];
echo "$name";
```

Este error es el que me da
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ciec1\addcrm.php on line 48

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El json_decode de ese resultado de tu pregunta (en formato json) devuelve un array (gracias al **true** usado como segundo parámetro), que quitando la paja hasta el valor que deseas, queda así:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [attributes] => Array
                (
                    [fi_expe_c] => 50176
```

Entonces, la sintaxis para sacar el dato seria:

```
$name = $datos['data']['attributes']['fi_expe_c'];
echo "$name";
```

Prueba y nos cuentas.

Comment: siiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii, master, muchas gracias por tu ayuda